# Common Pojo - Dynamic error message based on parent pojo - Spring validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a common pojo class account which is shared between creditor and debtor , I am trying to implement spring validation.

Debtor Class

```
public class Debtor {

         @NotBlank(message = "debtor name is missing")
         @SerializedName("name")
         private String name = null;

         @Valid
         @NotNull(message = "debtor account should not be null")
         @SerializedName("account")
         private Account account = null;
      }
```

Creditor class

```
public class Creditor {

     @NotBlank(message = "creditor name is missing")
     @SerializedName("name")
     private String name = null;

     @Valid
     @NotNull(message = "creditor account should not be null")
     @SerializedName("account")
     private Account account = null;
  }
```

Account class

```
 public class Account{

     @NotBlank(message = "accountno is missing")
     @SerializedName("accountno")
     private String accountno= null;

     @NotBlank(message = "accountName is missing")
     @SerializedName("accountName")
     private String accountName = null;
  }
```

The validation is working fine , i am able to catch and throw 400 for invalid request however , on the accountno and accountName validation , I would like throw specific message based on the parent pojo like

"debtor accountno is missing"
 "creditor accountno is missing"

How can i achieve this efficiently with spring validation , springboot ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create Spring custom validators. You will be able to create your validation code and you will not use the annotations for the specific field. You should implement Validator interface and then in your configuration class you need to override the 'configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener' method.

```
@Component
public class NameofClass implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return DomainClass.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        //validation code...
        if (o instanceof DomainClass) {
             // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this implementation will be able to access the class name when the validation is on the class field ? I don't think this implementation has any mention of the parent class.

Comment: What i am thinking is that the custom validation can start at the parent class and then it can check `debtor.getAccount().getAccountName == ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , This is how I did it , I will have to make use of the FieldError and getfield() method which gives the complete path of the request.

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();

    for(FieldError error : ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()) {
        log.info("FieldName : " + error.getField());
        errorMessages = getAllErrorMessages(errorMessages,error.getField(),error.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorMessages.toString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); 

 }

private List<String> getAllErrorMessages(List<String> errorMessages, String fieldName, String defaultMessage) {

     if(fieldName.contains("Debtor")) {
                errorMessages.add("Debtor "+ defaultMessage);
     }
     else if(fieldName.contains("Creditor")) {
            errorMessages.add("Creditor "+ defaultMessage);
     }
     else {
            errorMessages.add(defaultMessage);
     }
}
```